# Find referenced records with younger date compared to original record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can someone please help me with sql.

I have a table with fields:

ID (guid), DocumentNumber (varchar), RefDocumentNumber (varchar), DocumentDate(datetime).

Documents are paired, meaning:

(original document)

- ID: 1111-111...
- DocumentNumber: 1
- RefDocumentNumber: empty string
- Date:2014-06-25 12:11:24.890

(referenced document)

- ID: 2222-2222
- DocumentNumber: 2
- RefDocumentNumber: 1
- Date:2014-06-25 12:12:24.890

The problem is that i have some situations, where the reference document has "younger date". So i need to update its date with DATEADD function (add 60 seconds).

This has happened due to server time faul ...

Can somebody please help me with:

1. Finding this records (i want to know how many referenced documents needs to be updated)
2. Help me with "safe" update of this referenced documents (actually a loop of UPDATE MyTable SET documentdate= DATEADD (ss, 60, documentdate) where documentnumber = '1'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cursor to iterate through all records:

```
DECLARE curYoungRecords CURSOR FOR
 SELECT a.Id, a.DocumentDate
   FROM Documents a
        INNER JOIN Documents b ON b.DocumentNumber = a.RefDocumentNumber
               AND b.DocumentDate < a.DocumentDate

DECLARE @DocId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @DocDate DATETIME

OPEN curYoungRecords
FETCH NEXT FROM curYoungRecords INTO @DocId, @DocDate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Make record "older" by 120 seconds
    UPDATE Documents
       SET DocumentDate = DATEADD(second, -120, @DocDate)
     WHERE Id = @DocId

    FETCH NEXT FROM curYoungRecords INTO @DocId, @DocDate
END

CLOSE curYoungRecords
DEALLOCATE curYoungRecords
```

The `INNER JOIN` ensures only the "child" documents, where the document date is younger than the parent are included.

Comment: Note the update statement will set the "child" documents to the same date and time as the parent; is this the intended outcome or should it be older?

Comment: the intention is to ensure that the parent document has older date as the referenced (child) document. Currently because of wrong server time the child documents look like they have been created before its parent...

Comment: Given the sample data in the question is 60 seconds between the parent and the child I've changed the `UPDATE` to be 120 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE OD SET OD.Date = RD.Date
FROM Dokument OD
JOIN Dokument RD ON OD.DocumentNumber = RD.RefDocumentNumber
WHERE OD.Date < RD.Date
```

or:

```
UPDATE OD SET OD.Date = DATEADD(second,-120,OD.Date)
FROM Dokument OD
JOIN Dokument RD ON OD.DocumentNumber = RD.RefDocumentNumber
WHERE OD.Date < RD.Date
```

only the select stament:

```
Select DISTINCT OD.Id
FROM Dokument OD
JOIN Dokument RD ON OD.DocumentNumber = RD.RefDocumentNumber
WHERE OD.Date < RD.Date
```

Comment: First update sets the child date to be the same as parent date, not older. Also, adding 60 seconds to the date makes it younger, not older.

Comment: Edited. Anyway if the referenced record should be a copy of the Original Document so the first Update would be the better approach